# Let $T=\int_{0}^{x}f(y)dt$. Find eigenvalues and range of $T+T^*$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, adjoint-operators

> Consider $T=\int_{0}^{x}f(y)dt$ as a map from $L^2[0,M]$ to $L^2[0,M]$ find eigenvalues and range of $T+T^*$

I am pretty sure the solution is simple but I would like to make sure I am right.

By Fubini it is easy to see that $T^*=\int_{x}^{M}f(y)dy$ Thus $T+T^*=\int_{0}^{M}f(y)dy$ Hence the range are all constant functions and the only eigenvalue is $0$ as for any constant $a\not=aM$ ($M>0$)

Comment: *for any constant $a\not=aM$ ($M>0$)*... what if $M=1$?

Comment: @VIVID Well, you are right, if $M=1$ then $1$ is also an eigenvalue.

Comment: For your conclusion I think you have confused yourself with what an eigenvalue is. Take a look at the constant function $1$ on $[0,M]$. Then $(T+T^*)(1)=M\cdot 1$, so $M$ is also an eigenvalue.